# Unknown IP address on network (192.168.1.252)

Tags: router, ip

When scanning wireless and wired network, I find one IP address that is present which of the reason it is there is unknown to me.

I have tried to factory reset, and re-checked all settings in my router to find out how to shut the second IP down, changed my wireless password, but it's still there. I am not even sure why it's there to begin with.

My router's brand is ARRIS 192.168.1.1, and the second IP on my network is from ARRIS GROUP 192.168.1.252. What is 192.168.1.252 doing on my network. Why does my router have a second IP?

[image]

Comment: 192.168.1.252 is a special IP reserved for accessing the admin panel of routers. So it's not a host - it's your router.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router should show this IP address on one of its interfaces. If that isn't sufficient you can follow the associated MAC address on your switches.

A wired MAC address enables you to follow the cable. A wireless MAC that's still connected after you change the wireless password needs to have access to the password.

As @watchme has pointed out, another possibility is a secondary IP address on the router itself. You should consult your manual or the ISP on that.